# JPA query in multiple tables with many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

There are three tables: `Hospital`, `Medical_Service` and `Language_Service`,
Hospital can provide medical service and language service. So there are two many-to-many relationships.

[Simple ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfy6x.png)

Now I want to search hospital data with `postcode = 3000` and `medical service = Emergency`.

**DaoImpl:**

```
public List<Hospital> findByPostcodeAndMedicalType(String postcode, String medical) {
        String str = "SELECT h FROM Hospital h INNER JOIN Medical_Service m ON h.hospital_id = m.hospital_id WHERE " 
                + "h.Postcode = :postcode AND m.Medical_name = :medical";
        Query query = em.createQuery(str);
        query.setParameter("postcode", postcode);
        query.setParameter("medical", medical);
        return query.getResultList();

    }
```

Moreover, if I want to search by postcode, medical type and language from three tables, how to write a jsql.

**Warnings:**

> ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  Path expected for join!
>    Path expected for join!
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:378)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3858)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3644)
>
> > Apr 02, 2016 10:54:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
> >     SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/travel] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: **could not resolve property: Postcode** of: com.health.entity.Hospital [SELECT h FROM com.health.entity.Hospital h INNER JOIN Medical_Service m ON h.hospital_id = m.hospital_id WHERE h.Postcode = :postcode AND m.Medical_name = :medical]] with root cause
> >     org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Postcode of: com.health.entity.Hospital
> >         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
> >         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
> >         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
> >         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:367)

**Hospital.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Hospital")
public class Hospital {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
    private int hospital_id;

    private String hospital_name;

    private String postcode;

    private String suburb;

    private String address;

    private String type;

    private String category;

    private String longitude;

    private String latitude;

    private String email;

    private String website;

    private String phoneno;

    private String isemergency;

    private String agencytype;

    private String fax;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Hospital_Medical",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Hospital_id", referencedColumnName="Hospital_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Medical_id", referencedColumnName="Medical_id"))
private List<MedicalService> services;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Hospital_Language",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Hospital_id", referencedColumnName="Hospital_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Language_id", referencedColumnName="Language_id"))
private List<Language> languages;

//Setter and Getter
}
```

**MedicalService.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Medical_Service")
public class MedicalService {

@Id
private int medical_id;

private String medical_name;

private String description;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="services")
private List<Hospital> hospitals;
//Setter and Getter
}
```

**Language.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Language")
public class Language {

@Id
private int language_id;

private String language_name;

private String display_name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="languages")
private List<Hospital> hospitals;
//Setter and Getter
}
```

Comment: Can't tell you why FIELD "Postcode" of CLASS Hosptial is not found, since I can't see the CLASS. Perhaps the FIELD is not called Postcode? After all JPQL uses CLASSES and FIELDS not TABLES and COLUMNS.

Comment: Three entities are addd above

Comment: so there is no field called "Postcode". There is one called "postcode". Names are case sensitive in Java and they are also in JPQL. Also your "JOIN" is wrong ... you join through a relationship, not using ON and columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query might be wrong, which could be the cause of the problem.

You're currently using:

```
 SELECT h FROM Hospital h
     INNER JOIN Medical_Service m ON h.hospital_id = m.hospital_id
     WHERE h.Postcode = :postcode AND m.Medical_name = :medical
```

The problem might be that Medical_Service doesn't contain a Hospital_id field (used in the JOIN).

If you're happy to use native queries you could do this:

```
 SELECT * FROM Hospital WHERE Postcode = 3000 AND Hospital_id IN
    (SELECT Hospital_id FROM Hospital_Medical hm INNER JOIN Medical_Service m ON hm.Medical_id = m.Medical_id
    where Medical_name = 'Emergency')
```

The inner SELECT gets all of the Hospital_id's for hospitals that offer an Emergency service. The outer select then selects all hospitals where the Hospital_id is in the inner SELECT (i.e. they offer an Emergency service) but also only those with a postcode of 3000.

To use a native query you'd do something like this:

```
    int postcode = 3000;
    String service = "Emergency";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        sb.append("SELECT * FROM Hospital WHERE Postcode = ");
        sb.append(postcode);
        sb.append("AND Hospital_id IN SELECT Hospital_id FROM Hospital_Medical hm INNER JOIN "
                + "Medical_Service m ON hm.Medical_id = m.Medical_id where Medical_name = '");
        sb.append(service);
        sb.append("')");

    String queryString = sb.toString();
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString);
    List<Hospital> result = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: I have three entities added above. If I use native query, how can I give parameters in sql. And `Hospital_Medical` is a middle table for many-to-many relationship, do I need to add this entity as well?

Comment: @Frank2018 I've edited my answer to show the query being built and how you would pass in the parameters. With regards to querying `Hospital_Medical` you would have to use that because that's the table that tells you which hospitals offer the "Emergency" service.

Comment: It works! Thanks for your explanation! Can I ask you another question? If I want to search hospitals by **Postcode**, **Medical** and **Language**, how can I write the SQL?

Comment: @Frank2018, sure no problem. Please accept this answer here and ask your new question in a separate question. Just to keep things tidy.

Comment: Thank you! This is another question quick link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385393/three-joined-tables-query-with-many-to-many-relationship-in-jpa.