# Three joined tables query with many-to-many relationship in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

There are three tables: `Hospital`, `Medical_Service` and `Language_Service`,
Hospital can provide medical service and language service. So there are two many-to-many relationships.

[ERD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCb4e.png)

Now I want to search hospitals by three conditions: Postcode, Medical and Language, how can I write this SQL.

Comment: Hi Frank, welcome to SO. If you want help with a query please include the code that you've got to up to this point, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question? [JPA query in multiple tables with many-to-many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373154/jpa-query-in-multiple-tables-with-many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your SQL might look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Hospital WHERE Postcode = 3000 AND
Hospital_id IN
    (SELECT Hospital_id FROM Hospital_Medical hm
    INNER JOIN Medical_Service m ON hm.Medical_id = m.Medical_id
    where Medical_name = 'Emergency') AND
Hospital_id IN
(SELECT Hospital_id FROM Hospital_Language hl
    INNER JOIN Language_Service l ON hl.Language_id = l.Language_id
    where Language_name = 'English')
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like:

```
SELECT h 
FROM Hospital h JOIN h.medicalService m JOIN h.languageService l
WHERE h.postcode = :postCodeParameter 
AND m.medicalName = :medicalNameParameter 
AND l.languageName = :languageNameParameter
```

assuming your entities are mapped right.
Also the `HM_id` and `HL_id` column are unnecessary, it should be joined primary-key.

Comment: This is JPQL format, and only joined primary-key can work in this way?